# Select a checkbox when anywhere inside the table cell

Tags: jquery

I need a (jQuery) selector that says:

> Anytime there's a checkbox inside a table cell, then make the cursor a
>   pointer for that table cell and if the user clicks anywhere inside the
>   table cell, then click the checkbox for them.

I think I had this at one point, but that was before the days of the "on" selector and besides, I think it got me in trouble with an infinite loop at some point, so I took it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it. I went with event delegation with the `td`, as there can be a large number with `table`s, and it also gives you the flexibility to add more in the future via JavaScript and have them *just work*.

```
// Get some references to your elements.
var $table = $("#some-table");
var $tdWithCheckbox = $table.find("td:has(input[type='checkbox'])");    

// Alternatively, add a class which has `cursor: pointer`.
$tdWithCheckbox.css("cursor", "pointer");

// Use event delegation.
$table.on("click", "td", function() {
     $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", true);
});
```

Comment: I don't understand  if ($(this).is($tdWithCheckbox)).  What if there are a bunch of table cells with checkboxes?

Comment: @Phillip `is` can check if an element is part of another jQuery collection.

Comment: I think you lose the benefit of event delegation by assigning $tdWithCheckbox when the page loads, no?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:has` selector.

```
$('td:has(input[type=checkbox])').css('cursor', 'pointer');

$(document).on('click', 'td', function(){
   $('input[type=checkbox]', this).click()
})
```

Comment: Do I have to worry about bubbling?

Comment: @Phillip If your tds are generated dynamically `on` does the trick.

Comment: But what if they're not generated by JavaScript?  I think I need to stopPropagation somehow.

Comment: I also had to add :enabled to the criteria.  Just another thing to worry about.